How to report a bug agaist a snap package?
I recently answered a question about simple-scan unable to detect a scanner, and it turned out to be a snap-only bug (possibly a permission issue).
An Ask Ubuntu user suggested informing the snap packager of the issue.
It turns out that the packager is canonical (https://snapcraft.io/simple-scan), and there is no link to report an issue on this page.
I saw this question, but snap info simple-scan reverts me back to https://snapcraft.io/simple-scan, which does not have a bug reporting link.
And it would not be fruitful to report the bug at the simple-scan development site because they did not package it.
How to report a bug for such snap packages? It is most likely not a snapd bug, but a packaging issue.

This question is similar to: Where to report issues of snaps?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If emailing Canonical as suggested in this answer doesn't work out, I'd guess your best bet is to find the publisher's repo for that snap (if one exists) and file a bug report there. Simple-scan seems to be packaged as a snap here: https://github.com/ubuntu/simple-scan. There being no requirement to have an issue tracker to publish a snap, I doubt there will be a common place to post bugs.
